# FreeRTOS Queue Struct C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, queue, freertos

I do not understand how to declare a structure that I can use to send data between two threads in FreeRTOS.

I have two threads, the one should populate the struct with data, and the other one should read the data from the struct, which was sent with a message queue.

The data can be copied or via pointer, it is not large amounts of data.

In my main.c file I declare the structure and declare the queue and the queue handle:
Before int main(void):

```
xQueueHandle LED_Queue_Handle, ChannelFreqQueue;

    struct AMessage
{
        uint8_t channelID;
        float channelFreq;
};
```

In main I create the queue

```
ChannelFreqQueue = xQueueCreate(2, sizeof(struct AMessage *));
```

In the task that needs to send data to the queue:

```
static void StopCompThread(void const *argument)
{
    uint32_t count=0;
    uint8_t ActiveChannel =0;
    uint16_t uartcount =0;
    const float period = 0.0085;
    static float frequency = 0;

    for (;;)
  {
        struct AMessage txIdrisData;

        if(xSemaphoreTake(OscStopSem, portMAX_DELAY))       // Timer 17 Callback 8.5ms
        {
                    HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim17);
                    __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim17,0);       
                    count = __HAL_TIM_GetCounter(&htim3);
                    uartcount++;


                            uint16_t pinstatus = (uint16_t)GPIOB->ODR & 0x2000;
                            if (pinstatus == 0)
                            {
                                ActiveChannel = 0x01;
                            }
                            else ActiveChannel = 0x02;

                            if (uartcount == 525)
                            {
                                txIdrisData.channelID = ActiveChannel;
                                txIdrisData.channelFreq = frequency;

                                xQueueSend(ChannelFreqQueue, (void *) &txIdrisData,portMAX_DELAY); 

                            }

        }

    } //FORever

} // StopCompThread
```

And then the task that needs to receive the data from the queue:

```
static void IDRISThread(void const *argument)
    {
        struct AMessage rxIdrisData;    

        float temp = 0.0;
        uint8_t channel = 0;
        char IdrisDataBuf[11] = {0}; // 3 Bytes x 4 channels = 12 Bytes
        uint8_t IdrisStatusByte = 0;

        for (;;)
      {
          xQueueReceive( ChannelFreqQueue, &( rxIdrisData ), portMAX_DELAY );

            temp = rxIdrisData.channelFreq;
            channel = rxIdrisData.channelID;

            temp = temp * 1000;

            snprintf(IdrisDataBuf, 2, "%.0f",temp); // Channel Data - Counts/Frequency

            if (channel == 0x00)
            {
                IdrisDataBuf[2] = 0x00;
            }
            if (channel == 0x01)
            {
                IdrisDataBuf[2] = 0x01;
            }

            uart_send(IdrisDataBuf, 12);


        } //FORever

    } // IDRISThread
```

I am sure that I have a misunderstanding of how to declare and use the structure and also that I have pointers and non-pointers mixed up. I have tried to use this API doc as reference: http://www.freertos.org/a00118.html

If someone can point out my mistakes or help with pseudo-code that might help me understand it would be appreciated.

Comment: If you push `struct AMessage` into the queue, why do you use `sizeof(struct AMessage *)` when creating the queue? Types do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no room to store elements in your queue

```
ChannelFreqQueue = xQueueCreate(2, sizeof(struct AMessage *));
```

Creates 2 pointer element to `struct AMessage` structures.
What you need is 2 element array of `struct AMessage`

```
ChannelFreqQueue = xQueueCreate(2, sizeof(struct AMessage));
```

Comment: Assuming you have a 32 bit system your queue will be be 2 entries long, each entry of 4 bytes. When you send something to the queue only the first 4 bytes of your structure will be copied to the queue. When you receive from the queue only 4 bytes will be copied back into your structure. Assuming no padding your structure is probably 5 bytes long. So what LP said above is what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just queue the structure, rather than a pointer to the structure, it would be much simpler.  Read the blurb on the [FreeRTOS Queues documentation page](http://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Queues.html) and see the "Alternatives To Using Queue Sets" section half way down the [Queue Sets](http://www.freertos.org/Pend-on-multiple-rtos-objects.html) page.