# Send an struct array across a FREERTOS queue

Tags: esp32, freertos, arduino-esp32

I am starting with ESP32 and FREERTOS, and I am having problems sending an Struct array across a queue. I have already sent another kind of variables but never an array of Structs and I am getting an exception.

The sender and the receiver are in different source files and I am starting to thing that maybe is the problem (or at least part of the problem).

My simplified code looks like this:

common.h

```cpp
struct dailyWeather {
  // Day of the week starting in Monday (1)
  int dayOfWeek;

  // Min and Max daily temperature
  float minTemperature;
  float maxTemperature;

  int weather;
};
```

file1.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef _FILE1_
#define _FILE1_

// Queue
extern QueueHandle_t weatherQueue;

#endif
```

file1.cpp

```cpp
#include "common.h"
#include "file1.h"

// Queue
QueueHandle_t weatherQueue = xQueueCreate( 2, sizeof(dailyWeather *) ); // also tried "dailyWeather" without pointer and "Struct dailyWeather"

void task1(void *pvParameters) {
  for (;;) {
    dailyWeather weatherDATA[8] = {};

    // Code to fill the array of structs with data

    if (xQueueSend( weatherQueue, &weatherDATA, ( TickType_t ) 0 ) == pdTRUE) {
      // The message was sent sucessfully
    }
  }
}
```

file2.cpp

```cpp
#include "common.h"
#include "file1.h"

void task2(void *pvParameters) {
  for (;;) {
    dailyWeather *weatherDATA_P; // Also tried without pointer and as an array of Structs

    if( xQueueReceive(weatherQueue, &( weatherDATA_P ), ( TickType_t ) 0 ) ) {
      Serial.println("Received");
      dailyWeather weatherDATA = *weatherDATA_P;
      Serial.println(weatherDATA.dayOfWeek);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code on my ESP32 it works until I try to print the data with Serial.println. The "Received" message is printed, but it crash in the next Serial.println with this error.

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
```

I am locked with this problem and I am not able to find a way to fix it, so any help will be very apreciated.

EDIT:
I am thinking that maybe a solution will be just to add an order item to the struct, make the queue bigger (in number) and send all the Structs separately to the queue. Then use that order in reader to order it again.

Anyway, will be nice to learn what I am doing wrong with the above code.

Comment: See related posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822637/freertos-queue-struct-c?rq=1 and get more familiar with FreeRTOS queues. The API docs also contain useful examples. See e.g. https://www.freertos.org/a00117.html. Be very careful or better avoid send/receive objects by reference/pointer allocated on stack !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it's not a good idea to create the queue in the global scope like you do. A global queue handle is OK. But run `xQueueCreate()` in the same function that creates `task1` and `task2` (queue must be created before the tasks), something like this:

```
QueueHandle_t weatherQueue = NULL;
void main() {
  weatherQueue = xQueueCreate(32, sizeof(struct dailyWeather));
  if (!weatherQueue) {
    // Handle error
  }
  if (xTaskCreate(task1, ...) != pdPASS) {
    // Handle error
  }
  if (xTaskCreate(task2, ...) != pdPASS) {
    // Handle error
  }
}
```

Secondly, the code in `task1()` does the following in a loop:

1. Create a new array of 8 `dailyWeather` structs in stack (in the scope of a single loop iteration)
2. Copy a pointer to first item in `weatherDATA[]` to the queue (`task2` will receive it a bit later, when it's time to switch tasks)
3. Release the array of 8 `dailyWeather` (because we're exiting loop scope)

A bit later `task2()` executes and tries to read the pointer to first item in `weatherDATA[]`. However this memory has probably been released already. You can't dereference it.

So you're passing pointers to invalid memory over the queue.

It's much, much easier to work with a queue if you just pass the data you want to send instead of a pointer. Your structure is small and consists of elementary data types, so it's a good idea to pass it over the queue in its entirety, one at a time (you can pass an entire array if you want, but this way is simpler).

Something like this:

```
void task1(void *pvParameters) {
  for (;;) {
    dailyWeather weatherDATA[8] = {};

    // Code to fill the array of structs with data

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      // Copy the structs to queue, one at a time
      if (xQueueSend( weatherQueue, &(weatherDATA[i]), ( TickType_t ) 0 ) == pdTRUE) {
        // The message was sent successfully
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On the receiver side:

```
void task2(void *pvParameters) {
  for (;;) {
    dailyWeather weatherDATA; 
    if( xQueueReceive(weatherQueue, &( weatherDATA ), ( TickType_t ) 0 ) ) {
      Serial.println("Received");
      Serial.println(weatherDATA.dayOfWeek);
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot recommend the [official FreeRTOS book](https://www.freertos.org/fr-content-src/uploads/2018/07/161204_Mastering_the_FreeRTOS_Real_Time_Kernel-A_Hands-On_Tutorial_Guide.pdf) enough, it's a great resource for beginners.

Comment: Thanks for the point about how to create the queues and the link to the book. The next what I was planning to do was just that, raise the queue and send the items one by one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

freeRTOS queues operate by using the buffer and data size you specify during initialization, when you call `xQueueCreate()`, to make copies of the data you want to send-receive.

When you call `xQueueSend()`, which is equivalent to `xQueueSendToBack()`, it makes a copy into that buffer.

If another task is awaiting for the queue in a call to `xQueueReceive()`, at the moment it becomes ready to run, `xQueueReceive()` will make a copy of the item in front of the queue's buffer into the destination buffer you specify in your call to `xQueueReceive()`.

If the data you want to send is of pointer/array type, `dailyWeather *` in your case, then you need to make sure the memory pointed to by the pointer does not get out of scope before being read by the task that receives the pointer by calling `xQueueReceive()`. Local variables are created in the calling task's stack and will certainly get out of scope, and very likely overwritten, after the function returns.

IMO, best solution if you really need to pass pointers is to allocate the structures array in the function that generates the data and deallocate it in the task that consumes the data.

For many scenarios it is highly desirable not to abuse of dynamic memory handling, so in several communications stacks you will find the use of buffer pools, which at the end are also queues that are initialized during application startup. Operation is approximately as follows:

Initialization:

- Initialize the buffer pool queues (simple queues of pointers).
- Fill the buffer pools with dynamically allocated buffers of appropriated sizes.
- Initialize the queues for inter- task communications.

Task that provides the data:

- Get (Receive) a buffer pointer from one buffer pool.
- Fill the buffer with data.
- Send the buffer pointer to the communications queue.

Task that receives the data:

- Get (Receive) the data buffer pointer from the communications queue.
- Use the data.
- Return (Send) the buffer pointer to the buffer pool.

In case your structures are small, so you have a more or less constrained copy-then-copy overhead, it makes more sense to create the queue so you work directly with structure instances and structure copies instead of structure buffer pointers.

Comment: There's a lwIP port for NIOS-II processors that implements the buffers pool technique. They implement two buffer pools, one for "small" packets and one for larger packets.

Comment: Thanks!, Finally I have raised the queue size to fit all the items * 2, I have added an uint8_t variable to keep a track of the original position in the array, and then I read all the items in the destination task and I put them into another array created in that task.

Comment: Great to see you found your way. Maybe you would want to check [message buffers](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-message-buffer-API.html). These are very convenient too despite they would become inefficient for sending large buffers.

Comment: Thanks V.Lorz, but message buffers doesn't seems to fit my requirements. Anyway, they are interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all for the answers.

Finally I have added a variable to track the item position and I have passed all the data through the queue to the destination task. Then I put all those structs back into another array.

common.h

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

struct dailyWeather {
  // Day of the week starting in Monday (1)
  uint8_t dayOfWeek;

  // Min and Max daily temperature
  float minTemperature;
  float maxTemperature;

  uint8_t weather;

  uint8_t itemOrder;
};
```

file1.h

```cpp
// Queue
extern QueueHandle_t weatherQueue;
```

file1.cpp

```cpp
#include "common.h"
#include "file1.h"

// Queue
QueueHandle_t weatherQueue = xQueueCreate( 2 * 8, sizeof(struct dailyWeather) );

void task1(void *pvParameters) {
  for (;;) {
    dailyWeather weatherDATA[8];

    // Code to fill the array of structs with data

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      weatherDATA[i].itemOrder = i;
      if (xQueueSend( weatherQueue, &weatherDATA[i], ( TickType_t ) 0 ) == pdTRUE) {
        // The message was sent sucessfully
      }
    }
  }
}
```

file2.cpp

```cpp
#include "common.h"
#include "file1.h"

void task2(void *pvParameters) {
  dailyWeather weatherDATA_D[8];
  for (;;) {
    dailyWeather weatherDATA;

    if( xQueueReceive(weatherQueue, &( weatherDATA ), ( TickType_t ) 0 ) ) {
      Serial.println("Received");
      weatherDATA_D[weatherDATA.itemOrder] = weatherDATA;
    }
  }
}
```

Best regards.